# viewPager showing the same page every time

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm new to android development and no one else seems to be having this problem, so maybe I'm just dense.

Anyway, my issue is that my formatted viewPager shows the same string every time I change the screen. I used [this](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager) tutorial to create it, so my code is the same as that example code. How do I format the code correctly/ what should I add to my code so that a different screen shows up when I flip the page?

Edit: my code

**Home**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePager.ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

  }


  private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

  private ViewPager mPager;

  private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
      }
      else {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
      }
  }

public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

**ScreenSlidePageFragment**

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

**fragment_screen_slide_page**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
```

**Home.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="390dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ffweButton"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/homeButton"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: post you code plz

Comment: Where is the code you are using? How can we help you if you don't show the code? At least, the code you think is generating the issue

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with it, but I think it has something to do with one of those files. The other one is just the layout of the viewPager, which works fine.

Comment: it shows same page because your adapter is always returning same item `return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding fragments to your adapter like this

```
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "FRAG1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "FRAG2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "FRAG3");
```

then call it

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can you also post activity home.xml?

Comment: home.xml was added. When I add that to my adapter, addFragment and setAdapter come up with error messages saying the symbol can't be resolved, and no classes can be imported. Also, where would I call it?

Comment: @Mairead    I think the problem is on your public Fragment getItem method which you return ScreenSlidePageFragment. You should be returning an array or make a switch for other fragments too. In this case you are returning only 1 fragment.